# Stylesheet not updating, and not caching anywhere

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website and the stylesheet isn't updating for the server no matter what I try. It's not browser cache because I have sent it to a friend and he's having the same issue. The thing is the changes are being made in the style.css file when you type the URL in your browser but viewing from firebug shows the old styles.

I have even put a timestamp at the end of the CSS file to ensure that it is unique, still no luck.
Restarting Apache didn't do anything either.
I have Cloudflare in development mode, even though it's going through an a-record that isn't using Cloudflare.

I'm out of ideas here, this is driving me crazy.

Comment: Just check the link where you have added the stylesheet link:<link href="..\css\style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: Are you absolutely 100% sure you're updating the correct CSS file? Double-check the `<link>` element is pointing at the correct file.

Comment: I am 100% sure that it is loading from the CSS file. I've even tried removing the div styling from the CSS file and refreshing the page and the style is still there loading like nothing is wrong, and when viewing through firebug it is showing the style there. But then when searching the div styling on the actual css file when typing it into your browser the style is not there.

Comment: I'm damn sure that the issue is with the cloudflare developement mode. Did you turned on? Please double check. because I had the same issue and fixed in development mode

Comment: I have had it in Development mode even though the domain isn't having cloudflare traffic through it, and the issue is still there.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to delete the CSS on your server, restart apache, clear browser cache and refresh it again. When the page loads without the style (which it should hopefully load), add it back to the server, restart your apache and again refresh your browser. This will hopefully resolve your issue.

Comment: I did what you said and it loaded with the stylesheet like nothing is wrong, yet the style.css is not on the server.

edit: the style.css is still showing when entering the URL in the browser as well, and ingocnito loads with the stylesheet as well.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I’ll answer anyway. If the style.css is rendering differently from the root, it is because cloudflare is caching the old .css. You can check this by turning ‘Development Mode’ on. This will uncache everything. Check your cache settings to reset the new file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cloud flare in your site, just login to your cloud flare account and navigate Caching-> Configuration then look for the button PURGE EVERYTHING click it.. Do this every time you have html and CSS style changes.